# How to disable encoding using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am using REST template to intentionally send a % in request uri, something like `/items/a%b`

```
String responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("/items/a%b",
             requestObj.getHttpMethod(), requestEntity, String.class);
```

The `restTemplate` is converting the endoding of this uri and it is becoming `/items/a%25b` which makes sense as the rest template by default encodes the uri.

I tried using `UriComponent` for disabling the encoding of the uri

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/items/a%b").build();
URI uri= uriComponents.toUri();

String responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri,
             requestObj.getHttpMethod(), requestEntity, String.class);
```

But this is not working as the uri again is of type URI which do the encoding. I am sure I am not using the UriComponents the right way.

I would really appreciate if anyone could point out what's the right way of disabling the encoding.

Thanks.

Comment: The request you say you want to send is illegal. Why do you believe that you need a dangling percent sign?

Comment: I am writing a test to make the server handling it gracefully. Its for a full integration tests hitting a remote server. so nothing is mocked.

Comment: The server *shouldn't* handle it "gracefully", it should return a 400 error.

Comment: That's what I need to test that the server returns 400, but the problem is that the restTemplate client is not able to send the request. I tried it using fiddler and the clients are able to send the request with % in the uri.

Answer (score 14):

from the UriComponentsBuilder doc, exists method `build(boolean encoded)`

> `build(boolean encoded)` Builds a UriComponents instance from the
>   various components contained in this builder.

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/items/a%b").build(true);
```

Comment: This is the best answer when you don't want to stop encoding on all `RestTemplate` usages.

Answer (score 11):

**I feel this is best way to disable encoding in RestTemplate which works fine for me**

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    DefaultUriBuilderFactory defaultUriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
    defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
    restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(defaultUriBuilderFactory);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: It worked as expected.