# How to disable URL encoding in Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, resttemplate, url-encoding

```
String url = serverUrl + metadata.getUri();
response = restTemplate.exchange(url, metadata.getAction(), requestEntity, metadata.getResponseType());
```

url contains the string

> https://localhost/api/fm/info/dump/a\b\f\20170722_225714.jpg?lastModified=1507881481909

Spring RestTemplate encodes it to the following when requesting to server

> https://localhost/api/fm/info/dump/a%5Cb%5Cf%5C20170722_225714.jpg?lastModified=1507881481909

FYI, I need to disable URL encoding so that the '\' characters are available on server side as it is a business requirement since our web server (Nginx) has been configured to perform some checks based on the path of the request containing '\' character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable encoding using RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267371/how-to-disable-encoding-using-resttemplate)

Answer (score 13):

Create a `Configuration` class and add the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        DefaultUriBuilderFactory defaultUriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
        defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(defaultUriBuilderFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Then **Autowire** your `RestTemplate` in any class **through constructor injection**.