# Character decoding failed. Parameter [info] with value [%3] has been ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my API there is parameter info which is a request param and if the info value is %3 it shows me the error.
`Character decoding failed. Parameter [info] with value [%3] has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.`

I had created the RestTemplateConfig.java file to disable the decoding in the controller where API is called.

```
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplates() {
        DefaultUriBuilderFactory defaultUriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
        defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(defaultUriBuilderFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Request: `https://localhost:8080/home/app?info=%3`

```
@GetMapping("/app")
    public void appInfo(@RequestParam("info") String info){
     // logic
}
```

Then Autowire the RestTemplate in the class Through Constructor injection.
[How to disable URL encoding in Spring RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422472/how-to-disable-url-encoding-in-spring-resttemplate)

Comment: still issue exists ? \

Comment: yes, after writing the rest templates and autowired it in the controller. It is still showing me the error

Comment: please add the request code or some more data about the request

Comment: `https://localhost:8080/home/app?info=%3` is a malformed URI. `%3` looks like some escaped character was cut off (there should be 2 hexadecimal digits after the `%` sign).

Comment: I want to disable the URL encoding so that i can receive the info parameter.

Comment: if you want to receive  `%3` the client should encode de param value beacuse `%` is a special character. The client should encode `%` as `%25`, so pass `%253` as the param value.